# how to loop through each item of a MongoCollection?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a `MongoCollection`. I want to loop through each item. Normally I make a cursor, select some items with a query. Then I loop with the following through the cursor:

```
            foreach (CMongoJob job in oCollJob)
            {

            }
```

However, now I want to loop through all items, and the loop cannot go through the `MongoCollection`.

A solution that work is the following but seems stupid... make a cursor and a useless query that takes all item from the `MongoCollection`, then loop with the `foreach`

Comment: Well that's ur only hope with mongodb to use a cursor, becuase it is designed in this way..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need cursors. This is for most databases, and not just MongoDB. A database cursor is a control structure that enables traversal over the records in a database.

Cursors facilitate subsequent processing in conjunction with the traversal, such as retrieval, addition and removal of database records. The database cursor characteristic of traversal makes cursors similar to the programming language concept of iterator.

In addition, cursor is also useful to set sort, limits, batchSize, timeout etc. I would recommend to check out [MongoDB: Cursor Behaviours](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/cursors/#cursor-behaviors)